# SSIS fails when exporting from OLEDB data to Excel File

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

When debugging it sais in the Output:

> SSIS package "C:\Users\UserA\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\eSSIS\eSSIS\Package1.dtsx" starting.
>   Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation
>   phase is beginning. Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task 1,
>   SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning. Information: 0x40043006
>   at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is
>   beginning. Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline:
>   Pre-Execute phase is beginning. Error: 0xC0202009 at Data Flow Task 1,
>   Excel Destination [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqi8J.png): SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB
>   error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21. An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult:
>   0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated
>   errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was
>   done.". Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqi8J.png):
>   An error occurred while setting up a binding for the
>   "ShortDescription" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT". Error:
>   0xC0202025 at Data Flow Task 1, Excel Destination [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqi8J.png): Cannot create
>   an OLE DB accessor. Verify that the column metadata is valid. Error:
>   0xC004701A at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: Excel Destination
>   failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202025.
>   Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: "Excel
>   Destination" wrote 0 rows. Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task
>   1, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning. Task failed: Data Flow
>   Task 1 Warning: 0x80019002 at Package1: SSIS Warning Code
>   DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but
>   the number of errors raised (4) reached the maximum allowed (1);
>   resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches
>   the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the
>   MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors. SSIS package
>   "C:\Users\UserA\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\eSSIS\eSSIS\Package1.dtsx" finished: Failure.
>   The program '[11704] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0
>   (0x0).

Someone gave the answer below on [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f9492ba3-b6ac-4f2d-b52c-db86db5872e4/ssispipeline-warning-could-not-open-global-shared-memory-to-communicate-with-performance-dll?forum=sqlintegrationservices):

> You have to include the account you use to execute the package in the
>   performance counters group.

I would like to try out this workaround/answer but don't know how to include the account to execute a package. Please help

[image]

Comment: I believe your question has been answered [here.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic349843-148-1.aspx)

Comment: not really, this solution isn't realistic knowing that I have hundreds of tables, each table having 50 to 150 attributes.

Comment: It has nothing to do with global shared memory/performance counters. Everyone gets that warning. The problem is in this part: `The binding status was "DT_NTEXT"` `Verify that the column metadata is valid`. The Excel Jet driver is frustratingly useless at assigning data types. The main problem is that the final data type is decided by the length of data in the field so the required data type might actually change between different excel files. I've never found a solution myself